# Avoiding repeated Data Base calls for the same parameters using Java 8 or Spring data JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, spring-data-jpa

I am having a data base call which is in Oracle and i am using Spring data JPA for that.

I do have a function which utilizes this db call to retrieve the result every time in the loop.

Now my problem is most of the time the combination of parameter values are repeating. How to avoid this and is there a way to store temporarily for the given set of combination and the corresponding result set without any caching mechanism.

Any luck in Java 8 or spring data JPA itself?.

Comment: Show us some code, please. What did you try so far? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: so far i tried using equals and hash-code for that.

Comment: It adds to the list and next it checks whether the same exists then returns the index.

Comment: Don't post code in comments. Add it to the question please

Comment: And please post the code of this: "I do have a function which utilizes this db call to retrieve the result every time in the loop."

Comment: Have you considered stored procedures? It doesn't _eliminate_ the db call, but should give the db the opportunity to optimize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have various options.

1. If you are using Hibernate you may use it's query cache: https://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-hibernate-query-cache-work/ I'm not sure if EclipseLink has a similar feature.
2. You may use Springs caching facility. https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/
3. And of course you may role your own by assembling all the parameters in a single object with proper `equals` and `hashCode` implementation and store the result in a `HashMap`

Comment: Is there any mechanism in java 8..?,
What may be the problems that may occur if i use caching facilities..?

Comment: All this is applicable in Java 8. For caches with JPA all the pitfalls of caching and JPA apply. Especially caching outside the JPA implementation across sessions will cache detached entities.